# How to get multiple inner node values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlContent XML)

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1,
   '<location>
      <locationName>Loc1</locationName>
      <locationInchargeName>User1</locationInchargeName>
    </location>
    <location>
      <locationName>Loc2</locationName>
      <locationInchargeName>User2</locationInchargeName>
      <locationInchargeName>User3</locationInchargeName>
    </location>')

SELECT ID, E.P.value('locationName[1]','varchar(200)') as locationName, 
    E.P.value('locationInchargeName[1]','varchar(200)') AS locationInchargeName 
FROM @Test
CROSS APPLY XmlContent.nodes('location') as E(P)
```

This gives me the output of each location name with the first location incharge name.

```
locationName   locationInchargeName
-------------  ---------------------    
Loc1            User1
Loc2            User2
```

How do I get the names of all locationInchargeNames along with their location Name? Something like this:

```
locationName   locationInchargeName
-------------  ---------------------    
Loc1            User1
Loc2            User2
Loc2            User3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    XTbl1.Loc.value('locationName[1]','varchar(200)') as locationName, 
    XTbl2.InCharge.value('.','varchar(200)') AS locationInchargeName 
FROM @Test
CROSS APPLY XmlContent.nodes('location') as XTbl1(Loc)
CROSS APPLY XTbl1.Loc.nodes('locationInchargeName') as XTbl2(InCharge)
```